# Number of abelian extensions with bounded conductor.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

It's know that if $K|\mathbb{Q}$ is an abelian extensions then $K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$  for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ (Webber). We can define the conductor of abelian extensios as the minimum $m$ such that $K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_m)$. I'm wondering which is the number of abelian extension with bounded conductor. i.e let $m\in \mathbb{Z}$, compute the number of extensions such that $K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ for some $n\leq m$. 
Seems that it's "impossible" to find an explicit formula, but could you find it  an aproximation formula?
Thank you!

Comment: wouldn't you get this by counting the number of subgroups of $(\Bbb Z/n\Bbb Z)^*$ and then using the inclusion exclusion principle ?